# ggplot background in three different colours with geom_rect not working - with data and all code

Tags: r, ggplot2

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind("Thriving" = c(2, 2, NA, runif(9, 2.0, 5.0)), "Performance" = c(2, 3.5, 2.3, 4.2, NA, runif(7, 1.9, 6.9)), "Mastery_Climate" = c(runif(10, 2.2, 6.5), NA, 2.3), "Competitive_Climate" = c(NA, runif(4, 1.0, 3.6), NA, NA, runif(5, 1.5, 2.8)), "Collaboration" = c(runif(8, 2.2, 7.0), NA, NA, 5.5, 2.1)))
```

With this data I want to create bloxplots using the following command with the packages ggplot2 and tidyr:

```
df %>%
gather(key = "variable", value = "value") -> n
n$variable <- factor(n$variable, levels = c("Thriving", "Performance", "Mastery_Climate", "Competitive_Climate", "Collaboration"))
ggplot(data = n, aes(y = value, x = variable)) + stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max, geom = "boxplot", col = "#323232", fill = "#EFC76C") + 
coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
expand_limits(y = c(1, 7)) +
labs(x = "", y = "") +
theme(text = element_text(size = 12), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#EAEDED")) +
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 2, 0, 1.8),"cm"))
```

The function used in stat_summary is as follows:

```
min.mean.sd.max <- function(x) {
r <- c(min(x), mean(x) - sd(x), mean(x), mean(x) + sd(x), max(x))
names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
r
}
```

Now, HERE IT COMES: everything works beautifully, however, now I would like to colour the background in three different colours, green, yellow and red. I know that I have to use geom_rect for that. However, in order to have the boxplots in the foreground, I need to pass the geom_rect argument first - but this breaks my code:

```
df %>%
gather(key = "variable", value = "value") -> n
n$variable <- factor(n$variable, levels = c("Thriving", "Performance", "Mastery_Climate", "Competitive_Climate", "Collaboration"))
ggplot(data = n, aes(y = value, x = variable)) + 
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = 3, fill = "green"), alpha = .01) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 3, ymax = 5, fill = "yellow"), alpha = .01) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 5, ymax = Inf, fill = "red"), alpha = .01) +
stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max, geom = "boxplot", col = "#323232", fill = "#EFC76C") + 
coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
expand_limits(y = c(1, 7)) +
labs(x = "", y = "") +
theme(text = element_text(size = 12), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#EAEDED")) +
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 2, 0, 1.8),"cm"))
```

As you can see, I get the error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". From research I understand that this is because I needed to change the sequence and it now is a problem that the x-variable is a factor. However, I have been unable to solve this.
It would be great if all the other code could stay the same, it took me ages to put it together. Also, once the boxplots are in the foreground, it would be great if the grid behind would still be visible. Furthermore, I was so confused by the fill in geom_rect, I put in "green" and I get pink, or I put "yellow" and get blue - no clue why.
In any case, any help is very much appreciated. Many greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit: Updated answer with better shading control

I think this approach is more idiomatic to ggplot: this puts the shading into a separate table with numeric y values. In a modified ggplot call, all the y values are mapped as numeric values, but the labels for those values are swapped out in the `scale_y_continuous` line.

```
rects <- data.frame(xmin = -Inf, 
                    xmax = Inf,
                    ymin = c(0,3,5),  
                    ymax = c(3,5,Inf),
                    fill = c("green", "yellow", "red"))


ggplot(data = n, aes(y = value, x = as.numeric(variable))) + 
  geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill), 
            # Control the shading opacity here.
            inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.15) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max, geom = "boxplot", col = "#323232", fill = "#EFC76C") + 
  scale_fill_identity() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(unique(n$variable)), minor_breaks = NULL,
                 labels = unique(n$variable)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(1, 7)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#EAEDED")) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 2, 0, 1.8),"cm"))
```

[image]

---

#### Original answer

`geom_rect`'s coordinates should be pulled outside of the `aes()` call, and then I get a working solution. However, one problem with this approach is that the background rectangles are actually getting drawn once for each element in the source data, which is why the colors are so bright even with alpha = 0.01.

```
ggplot(data = n, aes(y = value, x = variable)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax =  Inf, ymin = 0, ymax = 3, fill = "green", alpha = .005) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax =  Inf, ymin = 3, ymax = 5, fill = "yellow", alpha = .005) +
  geom_rect(xmin =  -Inf, xmax =  Inf, ymin = 5, ymax = 7, fill = "red", alpha = .005) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max, geom = "boxplot", col = "#323232", fill = "#EFC76C") + 
  coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(1, 7)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#EAEDED")) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 2, 0, 1.8),"cm"))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help! So the only drawback is the brightness of the colour?

Comment: yeah, I just checked with a big dataset (n > 100) and then the colours get very bright ...

Comment: Updated the answer, should fix that problem now.

Comment: Excellent :) thanks a bunch, you saved me hours of frustration! I already accepted your solution as correct